# Rails strip_insignificant_zeros default set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app 99% of the time I want to strip_insignificant_zeros. So it's a pain to keep passing the option to the number_to_currency method. I want the default to be true. I figured this would be straight forward, locate the source code, overwrite the default.

So, I created a config/initializers file, and added the following but this the zeros are still present by default.

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper::NumberConverter::DEFAULTS[:currency][:format][:strip_insignificant_zeros] = true
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper::NumberConverter::DEFAULTS[:format][:strip_insignificant_zeros] = true
```

**What am I missing here?**

Version of rails and source code I referenced: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper/NumberConverter

Answer (score 4):

The - quite unexpected - problem with your approach is that there are actually **two default settings** in two separate places for the `number_to_currency` helper. One of them is the `DEFAULTS` constant that you correctly updated in your initializer.

But this is not enough: the `DEFAULTS` hash is **[merged](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.7/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper/number_converter.rb#L143) with the formatting settings defined in the locale**. You may not have any of the format settings defined in your `config/locales/en.yml` locale file but there is also a default locale settings file in `ActiveSupport`. As you can see from its [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.7/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml#L64), it has `strip_insignificant_zeros` set to `false`.

Another proof for this behavior is that if you place a new, an even empty, locale file in your `config/locales`, e.g. `my_locale.yml`, and try to call the converter under this locale: `number_to_currency(123, locale: :my_locale)`, your initializer settings will actually work.

So, the correct solution to this is to **define your formatting settings in your locale** instead of the initializer. So, the following minimal setting in your locale should work:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  number:
    currency:
      format:
        strip_insignificant_zeros: true
```